# How to say that I want to be pretty enough in fitness?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

In my question in Physical Fitness, [Is there a simple program that I don't have to look up at all?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/28539/15036), I am asked for the purpose of this plan:

> for what goal?

My goal is to have a good form of muscle that can be noticeable by eyes, but don't need to be so muscular. I want to answer this short and fluent, but I don't know how to say that. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can say "**I want to be in a good shape**". That is the best I could think of.

Comment: @onlyforthis I disagree, in good shape generally means that the person is fit, ie can do a decent amount of physical activity without being too tired and puffed out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're after, you might want to use the word *toned*.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toning_exercises) says:

> In this context, the term **toned** implies leanness in the body (low levels of body fat), noticeable muscle definition and shape, but not significant muscle size ("bulk").

Yet [another website](http://www.sparkpeople.com/resource/fitness_articles.asp?id=1662) says:

> **What Is Toning?**
>   When most people say that they want to "tone up," what they usually mean is that they want to become leaner. Basically, they want to lose fat, and add a little muscle definition—but not so much muscle mass that they look like a bodybuilder.

Comment: "but not so much muscle mass that they look like a bodybuilder". This.